# CS50P problem set 8 cookie jar check50 Error

Tags: python, cs50, cookiejar

I keep getting this error on the check50 while all other tests passes
can anyone help me plz.

":( jar's withdraw method removes cookies from the jar's size"
Cause
expected exit code 0, not 1

here is my code:

```
class Jar:
    def __init__(self, capacity=12):
        if capacity > 0:
            self._capacity = capacity
            self._size = 0
        else:
            raise ValueError
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.size * ''}"
    
    def deposit(self, n):
        if n <= self.capacity and n + self.size <= self.capacity:
            self._size += n
        else:
            raise ValueError
    
    def withdraw(self, n):
        if n <= self.capacity and n < self.size:
            self._size -= n
        else:
            raise ValueError

    @property
    def capacity(self):
        return self._capacity
    
    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n <= self.size`?  I am allowed to withdraw all of the cookies.  And you should never have to check capacity when withdrawing.  And you don't need TWO checks in `deposit`.  You need to check that the NEW size is within capacity.

Comment: thanks for the comment Tim
you are absolutely right the condition on withdraw should be n<= self.size, and it solved my problem, the capacity check on withdraw was my last attempt to solve the error before I post here and I forgot to remove it :)! for the condition on deposit also you were right there is no need to check if the n alone is less than capacity.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of Time Roberts, the condition on withdraw should be `n <= self.size`.
this is the solution for my probelm